# String pool memory alloaction

Tags: java, string, string-pool

```
String s = "abc";
String s4 = s + "";
System.out.println(s4 == s);
System.out.println(s4.equals(s));
```

This prints:

> false
>   true

Can anybody please explain why is it so?

Comment: This is a different dupe. The answer should be - *`s+""` creates a String instance on the heap..

Comment: This seems not a duplicate of pointed question

Answer (score 3):

```
String s="abc"; // goes to string constants pool
String s4 = s +"" ;// has value "abc" but goes on heap and not in string constants pool
System.out.println(s4==s);//well,, the references are not equal. There are 2 diffrent instances with value="abc"
System.out.println(s4.equals(s)); // equals() checks for value and the values of both insatnces are equal.
```

Comment: @user153 - because behind the scenes `s+""` will be done using a `StringBuilder` and then it will be converted to a `String` by calling `stribgBuilder.toString()`. So, this string will go on the heap. One thing to be noted is if s is marked as `final` , the `==` will give `true` because it will turn the entire expresssion `s+""` into compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with output in comment -

```
String s="abc";
String s4 = s +"" ;
System.out.println(s4==s); //false
System.out.println(s4.equals(s)); //true
```

First one is `false` because it is checking the reference of `s4` and `s`. Since these two reference are different it evaluated to `false`. Here `==` (the equality) operator, when applied on reference type, is used to check whether two reference are same or different.

`equals()` is a method which is achieved by every reference type from object class. You can override the equals() method for your own class.

The `equals(s)` method is used to check whether the two object are meaningfully equals or not. For `String` class the meaningfully equals means the two comparing strings are same but their references may be different. `String` class  has already override the `equals()`method and hence you need not override the `equals()` method by yourself.

Now for understanding string pool concept, consider the following code snippet -

```
String s5 = s;
System.out.println(s5); //abc
System.out.println(s5==s); //true
System.out.println(s5.equals(s)); //true
```

Here `s5==s` evaluated to true. Because `s5` is not referencing a new String object. It's referencing the the existing String object (that is - "abc" referenced by `s`) in the `string` pool. Now the both reference `s5` and `s4` are equals. In the last statement s5 and s are meaningfully equals and hence `s5.equals(s)` evaluated to `true`.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.